# Seeking a much simpler words to replace " forced" and " dispersal" in the sentence below

Tags: word-choice

Most of the defendants at Monday's hearing were detained during clashes which erupted in the southern province of Minya after the forced dispersal of two Muslim Brotherhood protest camps in Cairo on August 14.

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler. See [forced](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forced?q=forced) and [dispersal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispersal?q=dispersal) in a dictionary; these links are to the Oxford Dictionaries Online.

Answer (score 1):

"Forced" is a very basic word in English. If English vocabulary was like a box of crayons, "forced" would be in the eight-crayon box.

"Dispersal", on the other hand, might only be in the box of 64. A simpler term might be "scattering". As with all words, though, these *synonyms* are not identical. They don't mean *exactly* the same thing; they are only similar enough in meaning so that one can take the place of the other in certain circumstances.